# How to write a Serializer for array data in REST API in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have written basic model serializers in Django where the api mimics the data model. I now have a requirement to store User Preference in database. The api contains an array.

My User Models :

```
class User(models.Model):
    email_id = models.EmailField(max_length=80, blank=True, primary_key=True)

class UserPreference(models.Model)
    email_id = models.ForeignKey('User')
    preference = models.CharField(maxlength=20)
```

An ideal json post request would look something like this

```
{
    email:"abhishek@gmail.com"
    preference : [ 'books', 'food', 'lifestyle', 'travel']
}
```

I wish to save this json schema to the `UserPreference` model. This requires multiple inserts for preference.  What will be a good serializer design for it ?

I tried

```
class UserPreferenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPreference
        fields = ('email_id', 'preference')
```

Comment: Is the `Customer` model related to `User` in any way?

Comment: @mariodev Thanks for suggesting. I have edited customer to User.

Comment: You should write own model for preferences and use many-to-many field from UserPreference, or ForeignKey from the preference model.

Comment: @jaakko That's the correct behaviour I believe but I have stripped down my actual large use case to the part where I'm having a problem.

Comment: Did either of the answers work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make your model like this:

```
class UserPreference(models.Model)
    email_id = models.ForeignKey('User')
    preference = models.ManyToManyField('Preference') #create model for preferences
```

Then add custom create method to your serializer:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = self.context.get('user') #you can pass context={'user': self.request.user} in your view to the serializer
    up = UserPreference.objects.create(email_id=user)
    up.save()        
    preference = validated_data.get('preference', [])
    up.preference.add(*preference)
    up.save()
    return up
```

Answer (score 9):

you could use `StringRelatedField` of Django Rest Framework.

Make below changes and you will get the response in the way you want.

models.py (put related_name there)

```
class UserPreference(models.Model):
    email_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='preference')
    preference = models.CharField(maxlength=20)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    preference = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email_id', 'preference')
```